# Laravel call route from controller

Tags: php, laravel, routes, laravel-5

I am calling getting_started route after successfully login  :

```
protected $redirectTo = '/getting_started';
```

Here is my getting_started route code :

```
Route::get('/getting_started','UserController@getting_started');
```

And controller code :

```
public function getting_started()
{
    $id= Auth::id();
    $user = DB::table('user_profiles')->where('user_id', '=', $id)->first();

    if($user->dashboard_access == 0)
    {
        DB::table('user_profiles')
            ->where('user_id', $id)
            ->update(['dashboard_access' => 1]);
        return view('user.getting_started');
    }

    return view('user.dashboard');
}
```

It works perfectly and show in url :

> http://localhost:8080/getting_started

Now I actually want that if `user.dashboard` view is call it show in url like :

> http://localhost:8080/dashboard`

And on `getting_started` view show :

> http://localhost:8080/getting_started

It is possible to call dashboard route instead of :

```
  return view('user.dashboard');
```

My dashobard route is :

```
Route::get('/dashboard',['middleware' => 'auth', function () {
    return view('user.dashboard');
}]);
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

What I understand it is that you are looking for is this function

`return redirect()->route('dashboard');`

It's my understanding of your question which can be wrong. Maybe you are asking something else.

Comment: How to invoke a post route?

Answer (score 1):

That called **[Redirection](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/responses#redirects)** and especially you want to **[Returning A Redirect To A Named Route](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/responses#redirecting-named-routes)**, you route called `user.dashboard` so you could redirect to it using `redirect()->route(route_name)` :

```
return redirect()->route('user.dashboard');
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: How to invoke a post route?